# Javascript with jQuery in between document does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a piece of javascript/jquerycode, that's executed in between the document when a page loads.

What it does, is takes the height of a particular div, and assigns it to another div.

This works perfectly well in Firefox, but fails in the latest versions of all other browsers (Chrome, Opera, Safari, IE). I'm on Windows 7 Home Premium 64 Bit.

Here's the code. It goes below a `div` when the page is `generated`. Works only in Firefox, and nothing else.

```
'<script type="text/javascript;">'.
    '$(document).ready(function() {'.
        '$(\'.s\').height($(\'.entry\').height());'.
    '});'.
'</script>'.
```

Comment: might be because `text/javascript;` - remove the `;` and try... if yo use a type it should be text/javascript, text/ecmascript, application/javascript, and application/ecmascript or it should not be specified else the script tag will not be parsed as javascript

Comment: Egads!!! Who would have thought it was that? Worked now!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The think the problem is the type value you have specified. You have a extra `;` at the end of `type` attribute value.

So either change it to `text/javascript` or remove the type attribute entirely

[type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Attribute/script.type)

> This attribute identifies the scripting language of code embedded
>   within a script element or referenced via the element’s src attribute.
>   This is specified as a MIME type; examples of supported MIME types
>   include `text/javascript`, `text/ecmascript`, `application/javascript`, and
>   `application/ecmascript`. If this attribute is absent, the script is
>   treated as JavaScript.